# How can I get the progressive application of list of rules?

Tags: function-construction, replacement

I have a very long list of rules, and using this list of rules I want to see how some elements evolve as I successively apply the next rules on the previous rule.

Here is the simpler version of my problem, but I don't have any clue how to proceed. What would be an approach to this problem?

```
ClearAll[Evaluate[StringJoin[Context[], "*"]]]
Needs["Utilities`CleanSlate`"];
CleanSlate[];
ClearInOut[];

myRules = {a5 -> a4/a3, a4 -> a3 + a2,
           a3 -> a2^2 + a1, a2 -> a1 - 1, a1 -> b};
```

I wanted to get this list

```
{
    myRules[[1]] //. myRules[[2]],

    myRules[[1]] //. myRules[[2]] //.
    myRules[[3]],

    myRules[[1]] //. myRules[[2]] //.
    myRules[[3]] //. myRules[[4]],

    myRules[[1]] //. myRules[[2]] //.
    myRules[[3]] //. myRules[[4]] //.
    myRules[[5]]
}
```

Comment: Does `Rest@FoldList[#1 /. #2 &, myRules]` do the trick? Is that what you wanted? Something that just automates what you wrote down?

Comment: @march, If my question seems to be silly , i'm extremely sorry. Your code is super (just in one line). Truly thanks a lot.

Comment: The question's not silly.  I just wasn't sure what you wanted, so I asked to clarify in order to see if I should write an answer or not.  I have written an answer below.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here is a quick one-liner.

```
myRules = {a5 -> a4/a3, a4 -> a3 + a2, a3 -> a2^2 + a1, a2 -> a1 - 1, a1 -> b};  
Rest@FoldList[#1 /. #2 &, myRules]
(* {a5 -> (a2 + a3)/a3,
    a5 -> (a1 + a2 + a2^2)/(a1 + a2^2),
    a5 -> (-1 + (-1 + a1)^2 + 2 a1)/((-1 + a1)^2 + a1),
    a5 -> (-1 + (-1 + b)^2 + 2 b)/((-1 + b)^2 + b)} *)
```

Which is the same output as we get from the OP's code.

Alternatively, do

```
Rest@FoldList[ReplaceAll, myRules]
```

(Thanks to [Lukas-Lang](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/36508/lukas-lang).)

Comment: You should be able to write `ReplaceAll` instead of `#1 /. #2&` to improve readability (depending on who you ask of course)